# Headers and footers spanning both text and margin notes

Tags: header-footer, marginpar, marginnote

By default, headers and footers span only the width of the text body, but I need them to span  the width of the margin notes *and* the main text. The closest I've been able to get is the following, using the `headwidth` and `paperwidth` options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,marginparwidth=4cm,includemp,reversemp]{geometry}
\usepackage[headwidth=paper, footwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{left header}
\chead{centre header}
\ohead{right header}

\ifoot{left footer}
\cfoot{centre footer}
\ofoot{right footer}

\begin{document}

\section{Some text}

\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a margin note}

\section{Some more text}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Now the header is properly left-aligned with the margin notes column. However, the "right header" runs off the edge of the page. Clearly I need to set the headwidth to something like marginwidth + marginparsep + textwidth. However, I can't find anything about how to do this in the KOMA-Script manual (at least the English language version, `scrguide-en.pdf`).

I'm open to a solution with or without `scrlayer-scrpage`. I would prefer to avoid manually placing the header elements (e.g. using `textpos`) because I think it will be more difficult for others to maintain the code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `reversemp` option to `geometry`. Because of this a simple `headwidth=textwithmarginpar` does not work. However, you can use an additional offset:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,marginparwidth=4cm,includemp,reversemp]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth,footwidth=textwithmarginpar:-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth}

\ihead{left header}
\chead{centre header}
\ohead{right header}

\ifoot{left footer}
\cfoot{centre footer}
\ofoot{right footer}

\begin{document}

\section{Some text}

\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a margin note}

\section{Some more text}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: one page with head and foot]

Providing an offset is documented in the English KOMA-Script manual, section 5.5.

Note: Using an offset like `-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep` does not work as optional argument of `\usepackage` but only using `\KOMAoption` or `\KOMAoptions`.

Edit: The author of KOMA-Script told me that from KOMA-Script 3.39 on,

```
\usepackage[headwidth=textwidthmarginpar,footwidth=head]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

is sufficient if `scrlayer-scrpage` is loaded after `geometry` and `geometry`'s option `reversemp` or `\reversemarginpar` is activated before loading `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

This redefines pagestyle plain to generate wide headers by overlapping the edges.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,marginparwidth=4cm,includemp,reversemp,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{%
    \def\@oddhead{\hspace{\dimexpr -\marginparwidth-\marginparsep}%
      \rlap{\ihead}\hfill\chead\hfill\llap{\ohead}}
    \let\@evenhead\@oddhead% just in case
    \def\@oddfoot{\hspace{\dimexpr -\marginparwidth-\marginparsep}%
      \rlap{\ifoot}\hfill\cfoot\hfill\llap{\ofoot}}
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot% just in case
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    \let\subsectionmark\@gobble
    }
\makeatother

\def\ihead{left header}
\def\chead{centre header}
\def\ohead{right header}

\def\ifoot{left footer}
\def\cfoot{centre footer}
\def\ofoot{right footer}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\section{Some text}

\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a margin note}

\section{Some more text}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

This uses paracol to implement the marginpar area as a separate column.  Note that one can only use `\marginpar` between paragraphs.  OTOH, these marginpars will break over pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancyhead[L]{left header}
\fancyhead[C]{centre header}
\fancyhead[R]{right header}

\fancyfoot[L]{left footer}
\fancyfoot[C]{centre footer}
\fancyfoot[R]{right footer}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{\switchcolumn*
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}{\parindent=0pt\sloppy#1}%
  \switchcolumn}

\begin{document}
\setcolumnwidth{4cm}% uses \columnsep instead of \marginparsep
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn% start in right column
\section{Some text}

\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a margin note}

\section{Some more text}

\blindtext

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```