# How to place header in the corners of the page and align text with the left of the page

Tags: header-footer, geometry, page, tufte-book, head

I'm trying to replicate the pagestyle of Griffiths's book:
[image]

What I curently have is this (the text is in spanish, ignore it)
[image]

I need help to place the headers at the corners of every page and to place the text to the left of every page, leaving always white space at the right (opposite to the Griffiths's pagestyle). As an image, this is what I need:
[image]

The code I used to make the 2nd image is the following:

```
\documentclass[nohyper, nofonts, nobib, notoc]{tufte-book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\usepackage{physics} % recordar `physics2`
\usepackage[italic = false]{derivative}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{bbm} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[scr = rsfso]{mathalfa} 
\usepackage[c]{esvect}

\newcommand{\mbbm}[1]{\mathbbm{#1}}
\newcommand{\barra}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\vr}{\vb{\barra{r}}}
\newcommand{\mR}{\mbbm{R}}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\huge\MakeUppercase}{\thechapter.}{0.5cm}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{\topmargin + 1cm}{0.5cm}

\titleformat{name = \section}[block]{\bfseries\Large}{\thesection.}{0.25cm}{}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}   % Redefino con fancy el header
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
    \@mainmattertrue
    
    \fancyhf{}
    \newgeometry{
        tmargin = 10mm, bottom = 10mm,
        lmargin = 15mm, rmargin = 5mm,
        textwidth = 130mm,
        marginparsep = 5mm,
        marginparwidth = 60mm,
        includeall
    }
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    % \leftmark -> chapter, rightmark -> section
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thesection\quad\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{Cap\'itulo \thechapter\quad\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[RO, RE]{\bfseries\thepage}
    
    
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \fancyheadoffset{0pt}
    \fancyfootoffset{0pt}
    \setstretch{1.2}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter's title}\newpage
\section{Funciones especiales}
La ecuaci\'on de Laplace de una funci\'on $f:\mR^3\to\mR$ en cartesianas es
\begin{align*}
    \pdv[order=2]{f}{x} + \pdv[order=2]{f}{y} + \pdv[order=2]{f}{z} = 0,
\end{align*}
cuya soluci\'on se obtiene por separaci\'on de variables proponiendo $f(\vr) = XYZ$. En problemas donde hay simetr\'ia esf\'erica, dicha ecuaci\'on conviene escribirla en dichas coordenadas:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{r^2}\pdv{}{r}\biggl(
        r^2\pdv{f}{r}
    \biggr) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\pdv{}{\theta}\biggl(
        \sin\theta\pdv{f}{\theta}
    \biggr) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin[2]\theta}\pdv[order=2]{f}{\varphi} = 0,
\end{align*}
cuya soluci\'on tambi\'en se puede obtener por separaci\'on de variables, proponiendo $f(\vr) \sim R\Theta\Phi$. En el caso particular donde hay simetr\'ia azimutal (lo usual en electromagnetismo), $f(\vr) \sim R\Theta$. Por lo cual, reemplazando resulta:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{r^2}\pdv{}{r}\biggl(
        r^2R'\Theta
    \biggr) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\pdv{}{\theta}\biggl(
        \sin\theta R\Theta'
    \biggr) + 0 &= 0 \\
    \frac{\Theta}{r^2}\odv{}{r}(r^2 R')
    + \frac{R}{r^2\sin\theta}\odv{}{\theta}(\sin\theta\Theta')
    &= 0 \\
    \frac{1}{R}\odv{}{r}(r^2 R')
    + \frac{1}{\sin\theta\Theta}\odv{}{\theta}(\sin\theta\Theta')
    &= 0
\end{align*}
Si el primer t\'ermino es igual a una constante $\alpha^2$, entonces
\begin{align*}
    \odv{}{r}(r^2 R') - \alpha^2 R = 0, \qquad
    \odv{}{\theta}(\sin\theta\Theta') 
    + \alpha^2\sin\theta\Theta = 0
\end{align*}
Si $x \equiv \cos\theta$, entonces $\odif x = -\sin\theta\odif\theta$ y $x' = -\sin\theta$. Luego,
\begin{align*}
    -\sin\theta\odv{}{x}(-x'\Theta') + \beta^2 x'\Theta = 0
    \Leftrightarrow
\end{align*}



\newpage
\section{Ecuaci\'on de Legendre}
Cuando se resuelve la ecuaci\'on de Laplace en coordenadas esf\'ericas, la ecuaci\'on en $\theta$ que resulta del cambio de variable $x = \cos\theta$ se denomina \emph{ecuaci\'on de Legendre}:

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673642/headers-and-footers-spanning-both-text-and-margin-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a one-sided layout, i.e. the same layout on left and right pages. Is that correct?

That would then be:

```
\documentclass[oneside, nohyper, nofonts, nobib, notoc]{tufte-book}
```

And for the header/footer extension:

```
\fancyhfoffset[R]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
```

instead of

```
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{0pt}
```

By the way, you can use Unicode in LaTeX, so you can write `La ecuación de Laplace de una función` instead of `La ecuaci\'on de Laplace de una funci\'on` if you want.

Comment: Does matter if you place `oneside` first or last in the brackets of `tufte-book`?

Comment: No, shouldn't matter.